# Slide a 2d list rows if it has " " under it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2D array like this:

```
1,2,3,4

2,,,4,

1,4,,5

2,6,1,3
```

I need to slide the element with space character under it to be like this:

```
1,,,4

2,2,,4

1,4,3,5

2,6,1,3
```

What I have tried:

```
 def slide(x,y):

            if x>0:

                if Board[x][y]==" ":

                    Board[x][y]=Board[x-1][y]

                    Board[x-1][y]=" "

                    return slide(x-1,y)
```

But this doesn't work if the empty space isn't in a last row.

2 0""""""""

1 8"""""""4

5 4"""""""4

2 7"""""8 6

1 1"""""0 1 
ı wanna move the columns to right ıf there is a empty column at their right
2 0

1 8   4

5 4   4

2 7 8 6

1 1 8 1

Comment: Why use recursion instead of a loop on each column?

Comment: @Herion how did you build your array "Board"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort each column using *is not a whitespace* as key, for example:

```
board = [['1', '2', '3', '4'],
         ['2', ' ', ' ', '4'],
         ['1', '4', ' ', '5'],
         ['2', '6', '1', '3']]


def slide(ls):
    columns = list(zip(*ls))
    result = [sorted(column, key=lambda x: not x.isspace()) for column in columns]
    rows = zip(*result)
    return [' '.join(row) for row in rows]


for line in slide(board):
    print(line)
```

**Output**

```
1     4
2 2   4
1 4 3 5
2 6 1 3
```

Comment: that works great, can ı ask you ıf you know how to slide a column to right if the left column elements are all empty space char?

Comment: Could you put an example?

Comment: What would be the output for that example

Comment: I just add output for column part

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate first by row then by columns and swap the elements of the array. Note that if there is a space in the first row, it will swap the element with the last one (since the index is specified as `i-1` which leads to `-1`).

```
import numpy as np

lines = [['1', '2', '3', '4'],
         ['2', ' ', ' ', '4'],
         ['1', '4', ' ', '5'],
         ['2', '6', '1', '3']]

a = np.array(lines)
for j in range(a.shape[1]):
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        if a[i,j] == ' ':
            a[i,j] = a[i-1,j]
            a[i-1,j] = ' '
print(a)
```

Output

```
[['1' ' ' ' ' '4']
 ['2' '2' ' ' '4']
 ['1' '4' '3' '5']
 ['2' '6' '1' '3']]
```

Comment: It does not really matter. The idea is the same.